# Embedded feature vector components: position-dependent?

Tags: deep-learning, nlp, conv-neural-network, recurrent-neural-network, embedding

I have a question about the position of vector components of embedded features.

After the embedding layer, we usually flatten the embedded features to generate a 1D-shaped vector.

Assume we do not use CNN or RNN layers to process the embedded features, but go directly to the fully-connected layers to do classification:

**I wonder if the position of every vector component would affect the meaning of the whole vector to the machine-learning algorithm (e.g. in Keras)?**

Background of my question: In NLP, sentences have different lengths and the position of words with similar meaning does not always align. After vectorization of n-gram of words with embeddings, I wonder if it is possible to join the flattened embedded vector to the dense layer to do classification without CNN or RNN layer, which increases the size of my network + potentially cause overfitting to the training set.

Comment: You're only trying to classify one fixed-size window of text? (That is—an n-gram?) Also, what do you mean by 'meaning'?

Comment: Yes, I am using 3-gram of words -> index -> embedding layer to do the vectorization. What I meant for 'meaning', I suppose a component of vector encodes for a dimension of 'meaning' of the 3-gram of words, so I used the term 'meaning' here.

Comment: Without more information about your model specification, it's hard to understand what you're asking. You're saying that you want to classify this 3-gram, and your model puts an MLP on top of the vector for that 3-gram, then (presumably) a softmax to get class probabilities. Right?

Comment: Yes, you are right, that's the model structure (or add dense layers before the softmax single node). Is it logically sound to connect an embedded layer directly to the softmax? Thanks Arya!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about ML theory and/or methodology - please see the intro & **NOTE** in the `machine-learning` [tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info).

Comment: Yeah, this belongs on [stats.SE] instead.